# How to strip the <html> Tag from string?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have the following response from an HTTP get.

```
<HTML><BODY>Now='11/7/2017 4:08:34 PM' Process='chrome' SessionID=1 User='Local\User' Culture='en-US'<BR></BODY></HTML>
```

I need to get the data there in the body into a JSON object. So I tried to remove HTML tags. Though it is different, I have tried, as there in this **[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)**. It works for HTML tags but not for `<html>` itself.

I have tried also as below:

```
var content = "<HTML><BODY>Now='11/7/2017 4:08:34 PM' Process='chrome' SessionID=1 User='Local\User' Culture='en-US'<BR></BODY></HTML>";

var tag = document.createElement("html");
tag.outerHtml = content;
```

It gives the following error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node.
```

Though I know that it can be achieved with `regex`, I want to do it without `regex`.

Could someone resolve it?

Comment: Why dont you want to use a regex? Cant you do it 'ugly' with String.replace?

Comment: To my understanding, your main problem and provided solution have nothing in common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DOMParser()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to convert the string of HTML into a DOM:

```js
var html = `<HTML><BODY>Now='11/7/2017 4:08:34 PM' Process='chrome' SessionID=1 User='Local\User' Culture='en-US'<BR></BODY></HTML>`;

var parser = new DOMParser();
var html_dom = parser.parseFromString(html, "text/html");
var body = html_dom.querySelector("body");
var content = body.innerHTML;
console.log(content);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Quentin, this is what I exactly want. :)

Answer (score -2):

Just created a simple `codepen`. Please try, it shall work:

```
https://codepen.io/vishalkaului/pen/rYMGoy
```

`+6` and - 16 are to exclude the content before the starting`<BODY>` tag and after the closing `</BODY>` tag. It includes both the exclusion for the `<BODY></BODY>` tags.

```
(function () {
    let serverResponse = "<HTML><BODY>Now='11/7/2017 4:08:34 PM' 
    Process='chrome' SessionID=1 User='Local\User' Culture='en-
    US'<BR></BODY></HTML>";



 console.log(serverResponse.substr(serverResponse.indexOf('<BODY>')+6,serverResponse.indexOf('</BODY>')-16));
})()
```

**Note:**
This solution caters only when you know that the structure of the response is same. Though, content can vary but the tags are same before and after the response data.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Kindly have some patience, I was still in mid of posting the complete solution.

Comment: Patience? Because you were too impatient to finish typing your answer before clicking the "Post Your Answer" button?

Comment: "This solution caters only when you know that the structure of the response is same" — Which makes it very fragile and a poor approach to the problem.

Comment: Guess, we are here to help each other rather than putting someone else down.

Comment: I agree that's why I mentioned in the `Note` section. It's applicable they know the structure is same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158411/discussion-between-vishal-kaul-and-quentin).